# Oracle database has virtual data?

Tags: php, oracle, qt, stored-procedures

I have oracle database and I connect to it with Android in Qt with php. And I have stored procedures which I call.
Problem is when I use sqlplus I can see that I have deleted all rows in database but when accessing through the Android I can still see data that I have deleted.

How to change this?

Comment: Try typing "commit" in sqlplus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are remembering to COMMIT, right?

Comment: Same thing happens when I perform some other command from code. Like update. Do I need to put commit into procedure?ž

Comment: Yes.  INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE changes are only visible to other sessions after a COMMIT.